# Preventing SQL injection by parsing integer out of input

Tags: java, jsp

I have this code for my Secure Software development course. Our goal in this assignment is to prevent SQL injection attacks by validating the input using a prepared statement or parsing integers out of the possible attack input.
Now I am relatively new to programming and I am taking Java along with this course (secure software development fundamentals) and I cannot really wrap my head around solving this problem very efficiently.
However, I have come up with a code that parses the integer from an possible attack input and only uses that as parameter for file name in the code but I don't really know how and where plug it into the original vulnerable code to make is secure.
Here is the original code which is vulnerable to SQL injection attack:

```
<%@page import="java.io.DataInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>

<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSetMetaData"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.cysecurity.cspf.jvl.model.DBConnect"%>


<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%
  String path = request.getContextPath();
  try
  {
    String fileid=request.getParameter("fileid");
    if(fileid!=null && !fileid.equals(""))
   {
     Connection con=new DBConnect().connect(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/config.properties"));
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs =null;

             // the following code is vulnerable to injection attack:
             rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from FilesList where fileid="+fileid);         
              if(rs != null && rs.next())
              {
                
                int BUFSIZE = 4096;
                String filePath=rs.getString("path");
                  
                 File file = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath(path));
                file = new File(file.getParent()+filePath);       
                int length   = 0;
                ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
                String fileName = (new File(filePath)).getName();
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" +new Random().nextInt(10000)+ "\"");

                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE];
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

                while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(byteBuffer)) != -1))
                {
                outStream.write(byteBuffer,0,length);
                }

                in.close();
                outStream.close();
              }
              else
              {
                  out.print("File Not Found");
              }
    }
    else
    {
        out.print("File Parameter is missing");
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
       out.print("Oops, Something Went wrong");
  }
    %>
```

So I have come up with this code that extracts only the first integer from a possible attack and uses it as the fileid parameter. It also advices if a possible attack may be in progress:

```
package parseInt;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParsePosition;

public class testParseInt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //String value = "1".trim();
        //String value = "1%20and%20char_length(database())=1".trim();
        String value = "a1%20and%20char_length(database())=1".trim();
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
        Number parsed = formatter.parse(value, pos);
        
        if ( pos.getIndex() !=  value.length() || pos.getErrorIndex() != -1) {
            System.out.println("Parsed value=" + parsed + " but parameter value=" + value);
            System.out.println("Possible SQL Injection attack in progress!!!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Parsed value=" + parsed);
            System.out.println("This is a safe request");
        }
        if (parsed == null) {
            
        }
    
    }

}
```

How and where I can plug my code (with modification) into the original code so that I can secure the code an prevent SQL injection attacks?

Comment: The best way is to not do it yourself: Create a query that has parameter placeholders, eg `stmt.createQuery("select * from FilesList where fileid=?")`. Call `setParameter()` to set the parameters. Then execute it.

Comment: So in this assignment we are supposed to use parsing integer method and plug it somewhere in the code to mitigate the vulnerability. I want to modify the original code in such a way that it would get the request but only use the first digit (if any) and use it as fileid parameter. After I fix this I am supposed to create new WAR file out of it and deploy it in tomcat so that if attacked, it does not result in exploit.

Comment: By learning Java and secure programming at the same time you have probably bitten off more than you can chew.

Comment: You might be correct. I think I would have been better off if I took this course next semester. Another difficulty that we faced was that the class was online and it was very difficult to get directions from our instructor and troubleshoot setting up required software (Docker, tomcat, etc). I will definitely come review the materials of this course again after I have a more solid Java knowledge.